# I can't display everything from my table, it only displays the last record

Tags: php, mysql

Hey Guys I'm having a hard time printing everything from my table in mysql. 
It only prints the last record of the table. Thank you in advance.

Here's my syntax:

```
//query
$search_query="SELECT offer_no,day,time from offer where subject_id = '"              .$search_subject_id ."';";  

//execution of query    
$result = mysql_query($search_query,$dbhandle); 

//fetching result
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $results =$row['offer_no'] . "     " .$row['day']. "     " .$row['time'];
 }
```

**Output:**

```
1001 MWF 7:00-8:00
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1001 MWF 7:00-8:00, 1002 MWF 8:00-9:00
```

Comment: Did you try to figure out what your loop does?

Comment: Your conditional part `where subject_id = '"              .$search_subject_id ."';"` may filter record. W

Comment: `$results = "hello"; $results = "world"; print $results;` <- what do you think this will print?

Comment: i've already run the query in phpmyadmin. it displays 2 records as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append each row to a variable, currently, you are overriding the value, leaving only the last one. Try this:

```
//query
$search_query="SELECT offer_no,day,time from offer where subject_id = '"              .$search_subject_id ."';";  

//execution of query    
$result = mysql_query($search_query,$dbhandle); 

$output = "";

//fetching result
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $output .= $row['offer_no'] . "     " .$row['day']. "     " .$row['time'];
}

echo $output;
```

Notice the `.=` this is shorthand for concatenation of strings to variables.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use either concatenation or array because `$results` will be reset on each loop and finally takes the last result:

Array:

```
  $results[] =$row['offer_no'] . "     " .$row['day']. "     " .$row['time'];
```

Or:

```
  $results .=$row['offer_no'] . "     " .$row['day']. "     " .$row['time'];
```

Please note: mysql_* function were deprecated, you can switch to mysqli and PDO and use parametrized query to prevent SQL Injection Attack.

Comment: your syntax displayed 2 records but it had a Notice/Error.
This is what i got: 
Notice: Undefined variable: results in C:\xampp\htdocs\user\student.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined variable: results_info in 

Line 29:  $results .=$row['offer_no'] . "     " .$row['day']. "     " .$row['time'];

Comment: @ErnestFaytone you get notice when you use `.=` on `$results` without defining it first. Just define `$results` before doing concatenation. And second variable `$results_info` is not in any code presented.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $results[] =$row['offer_no'] . "     " .$row['day']. "     " .$row['time'];
  }

 $result_string = "";
 if(is_array($results))
 {
    $result_string = implode(",",$results) 
 }
 echo $result_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

It always assigns new variable try this one

```
$results =$results.",".$row['offer_no'] . "     " .$row['day']. "     " .$row['time'];
```

let me know if it not work.

Comment: you can use if for that I mean if it $i == 0 then no comma or any other logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `$results` as an `array` like

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $results[] = $row['offer_no'] . "     " .$row['day']. "     " .$row['time'];
}
```

You are appending the values to an variable eachtime.So it will holds the last element in the array of `mysql_fetch_array` for the result.But you need to assign them to an array then it will maintain the assignments of those array elements in the form of an array `$result`.If you print the `$results` then you will get the deserver output.

You can also append the results to the $results **variable** on `concating` the results like

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $results .= $row['offer_no'] . "     " .$row['day']. "     " .$row['time'];
}
echo $results;
```

And try to avoid `mysql_*` statements due to the entire `ext/mysql PHP` extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix `mysql_*`, is officially deprecated as of `PHP v5.5.0` and will be **removed in the future**.

There are two other `MySQL` extensions that you can better Use: `MySQLi` and `PDO_MySQL`, either of which can be used instead of `ext/mysql`.